# Can SignalR be used in this scenario?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, signalr

I need help with an approach i am taking.

So i have this scenario where i am getting data from database using DataReader in one of my MVC applications. At the end point (that is the web api controller) i am returning data as an `IEnumerable<>` type.

I am using `foreach()` to read one row at a time from IEnumerable and returning the data to client using SignalR. So the client calls a method on the server side and the server starts streaming data continuously (row by row).

Now i wanted to return data in chunks instead of one row at a time, i managed to modify the foreach loop and return 'n' rows at a time (so now it sends n rows at once), but it sends them continuously until it runs out of data and then closes the connection.

The reason why i am sending data in chunks is, to show the data in pages on UI (Angular).

My question here is, can i make the SignalR call on demand, like it sends the first 10 rows, then wait for the client to click next page and starts sending from 11 to 20 rowas again and so on.. (I am trying to avoid database call for each client call, so the loop should start where it was before).

I am not giving the client an option to jump to certain page (just page after page).

Also i would like to know if we can maintain the state of previous pages, so that if client wants to go to previous pages. (I don't think it's possible without saving the data in-memory somewhere which i am trying to avoid).

Please tell me if SignalR can be used in this scenario. If not, what would be a good approach for this?

I am new to SignalR and I am a beginner in C# as well, so please go easy on me.

Let me know if you need any further clarification.

Comment: Sorry. Your question is too broad to be answered in a simple way. Please try to rephrase it and avoid comments like "I should have mentioned this in question". And it would be nice to see some simplified sample you already tried.

Answer (score -1):

I wonder if you mean "should SignalR be used in this way?".

Your issue isn't really a SignalR issue. You may want to add pagination to your api, make your queries in a single request, grab what you need close your connection and return that data to the client.

Now, if the user is clicking to load more data, that is a request (Pull), there's no need for SignalR (Push).

This may not be the most scalable use of SignalR.

Comment: I cannot restrict the data at database level. I should have mentioned this in question. So i cannot modify the query in runtime to make it grab just n rows per call.